# Change email account address in Mac Mail without re-adding a new account

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

Ive got a computer running Mac Mail on OSX 10.12.

For one of my email accounts which is hosted with Google Apps For Business (Gmail) i have recently changed the email address from `alpha@domain.com` to `beta@domain.com`. These are not separate email accounts, but rather the same account with its name changed and still retains all its emails dating back 4 years.

How can i update Mac Mail to interact with the new email address without having to setup a new email address in Mac mail for `beta@domain.com` which would have to re download all the old emails ?

Comment: Why are you concerned with redownloading all the old emails?  Can you just leave the emails on google's servers and save yourself gigabytes of HD space?

Comment: @fsb , just because there are about 10gb, i already have them on my machine, so i dont want to delete them and have to re download them all. Out of interest is there a way i can set Mac Mail to only reference and give me access to the emails on gmail's server, rather than download them all ?

Comment: Do you have gmail setup as IMAP or POP?  If IMAP, then Mail will keep all the email on google's servers and you have access; the email isn't downloaded to your Mac. [Here's an explanation](http://pop2imap.com/apple-mail-gmail.php) of the methods and how to set it up.

Comment: @fsb Im using the Gmail integration that Mac Mail has nativly, which i beleive uses IMAP

Comment: If you haven't changed from the default IMAP to POP then your email is being stored on google.  You can test this by adding the updated email address and giving it time to sync your old email.